# Not able to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04

I tried to upgrade my distro from 19.10 to 20.04 using the command `update-manager -d`. It showed me that new version 20.04 was available and I could upgrade. When I chose the upgrade option it gave me the following resultts in the terminal.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was 
 imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import 
 to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit.py:33: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 
 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') 
 before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as WebKit
 authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
 extracting 'focal.tar.gz'
```

After this the process suddenly stops and everything goes back to as it is. I am not able to do the upgrade.

Edit: The content of /etc/apt/sources.list is in the below image
[Ubuntu Source List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egydR.jpg)

Comment: Back up your data and do a clean install of focal

Comment: you updated all packages to the newest versions before running update-manager? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y`

Comment: What does `sudo apt-cache show ubuntu-release-upgrader` tell you?

Comment: Yes I have upgraded all the packages to latest versions. When I run the command `sudo apt-cache show ubuntu-release-ugrader` as suggested by @starkus. It shows `N: Unable to locate package ubuntu-release-upgrader
E: No packages found` . I dont't want to clean install 20.04 because I have so many pre-installed libraries and packages that I use everyday. Please suggest me some workaround

Comment: Could you please post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.d/`?

Comment: The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` is in the below image
[Ubuntu Source List][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egydR.jpg 

But the file sources.d is empty :(